# JQuery selector: id ends with dynamic value

Tags: jquery

I am wondering if i there is a way i can use this selector with dynamic value in jQuery.

```
$("[id$=someValue]")
```

so i can select all the elements that ends with this dynamic value in my HTML page

Comment: May be you need `$("[id$='"+ someValue+"']")`, Here `someValue` is a varaible

Comment: this seems to work! can where should i put another string to add with "someValue" if want to

Answer (score 1):

```
$('[id*="someValue"]')
```

if the id contains part of the expression inside the quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("[id$='someValue']");
```

Should work, note the value being enclosed in quotation marks.